# web3js decodeLog fails with UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: web3js, transactions, events, uniswap

I am trying to decode transaction receipt log data from a [uniswap v2 transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8b2cc7b475b5711bd6fa61a1ff1f5737a9bc3fc3cd073110ad01f9f1191d7a90), but when I call `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog` it throws following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: invalid type (argument="type", value="_factory", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

I downloaded ABI from the ABI link at the bottom of [Uniswap V2 Router 2](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02) page

Here's the function I use:

```js
let uniswapV2Router2ABI = require("../abi/uniswap-v2-router-2.json");

async function getTransactionLogs(transactionHash) {
  let transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(
    transactionHash
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < transactionReceipt.logs.length; i++) {
    const log = transactionReceipt.logs[i];
    const decodedLog = web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(
      uniswapV2Router2ABI,
      log.data,
      log.topics
    );
    console.log("Log: ", JSON.stringify(decodedLog));
  }
}
```

Comment: The transactoin receipt contains log entries for all contract interactions during the execution. So it is possible that you were trying to decode a log entry from another contract (the Pair, the Tokens, etc).

Comment: @Ismael - Yes, you're right, that was the issue.